# Transpose option- multiple columns to single cell with a semi colon in between each value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

INPUT ( Multiple cells) (1 entry per cell) (Rows)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

EXPECTED OUTPUT - ( IN A SINGLE CELL) 
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10

Comment: Depending on your Excel license you can use the `TEXTJOIN()` function. Otherwise you have to go into VBA

Comment: Is this a question?  It looks more like a list of statements.  You may want to check [ask] and look at how to write a [mcve]

Comment: If you have Excel 2010+, you can do this using `Power Query` aka `Get&Transform`.  Post what you have tried and where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, depending on your Excel license you can make use of the `TEXTJOIN` function:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A1:A10)
```

If you have no access to this function, you will have to try some VBA, possibly a UDF which can be called on the worksheet:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(del as string, rng As Range) As String
    TEXTJOIN = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.Value), del)
End Function
```

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",A1:A10)
```

Comment: Just as clarification, TEXTJOIN is only available in Excel for Office 365, Excel for Office 365 for Mac, Excel for the web, Excel 2019, Excel 2019 for Mac, Excel for iPad, Excel for iPhone, Excel for Android tablets, Excel for Android phones and Excel Mobile